# Problem with Google strategy (Passport.js + MERN)

Tags: google-oauth, passport.js, mern

I am developing a MERN project with friends where we have installed Passport. We created our local strategy that works well but then we decided to go further and try to do something else using Google's. It's our first time using it.

Our problem is the logout: the user's login works and it is authenticated but we can't get out. Once we click the button that calls our logout function, the user disappears from the app but returns when we refresh the page. My friends and I think the main cause of this problem is related to a useEffect hook on our Header component which also has an async function named googleAuthentication because it never stops bringing the user's information from the back-end. We tried different things to rebuild this hook's logic but we still haven't found a solution.

This is our Google strategy, just in case:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const User = require('../models/User')
const passport = require('passport')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

function generatePassword() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'); // genera contraseña aleatoria, modulo que viene de node JS "CRYPTO"
}

module.exports.googleStrategy = async function(passport) {passport.use("google",
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback",
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
  },
  
  async function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    let userGoogle = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

    if (!userGoogle) {
      userGoogle = new User({
        googleId: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        password: generatePassword(),
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        profiles: [{ image: profile.photos[0].value, name: profile.name.givenName, myList: [] }]
      });
      
      await userGoogle.save();
    }

    return cb(null, userGoogle);
  }
  ))}
```

Our google auth routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport =  require ('passport')


router.get('/login/success', (req,res)=>{
    if (req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            message:"Successfully loged in",
            user:req.user,
            error:false
        })
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({error:true , message:"User not authenticated"})
    }
})

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope : ['profile', 'email']}))

router.get('/google/callback',
 passport.authenticate('google', 
  { successRedirect:'http://localhost:3000/',
    failureRedirect: '/signin' }), 
);


module.exports = router
```

Our Header component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext , useEffect} from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import '../sketch.css'
import {NavLink, Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

function Header(){
  const {user , setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
  const navigate = useNavigate()
   // Al cargar el componente, verificamos si la información del usuario está en localStorage
   useEffect(() => {
    const savedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (savedUser) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(savedUser));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  async function googleAuthentication() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/auth/login/success', { withCredentials: true });
    console.log(response)
    if (response.data.user && response.data.error === false) {
      setUser(response.data.user);
    }
  }
  googleAuthentication();
}, []);

  const LogOut = async () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
    const data = await axios.request({method:"GET",url:"http://localhost:3001/logout"})
    console.log(data)
    setUser(false)
    navigate("/")
  }

  return (
    <>
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between py-4 px-5">
            <img src="/logo.png" alt="Movies Hub" class="logo"/>
            <div class="header-content d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
             <NavBar></NavBar>
                <a href="#search"><button class="btn-search"><i class="bi bi-search px-5"></i></button></a>
                { user ?(
                  <div className='dropdown'>
                    <button className='btn px-4 colorButton ms-2 dropdown-toggle' type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{user.name}</button>
                    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <Link to="/profiles" className="dropdown-item hoverModal">Profiles</Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item hoverModal" onClick={LogOut}>Logout</Link>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                ) : ( <NavLink to="/signin"><button class="btn px-4 colorButton ms-2">Sign in</button></NavLink>
                )} 
            </div>
        </header>
  
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Thanks for reading.